# Question on a sufficient condition of contractiveness of best reply functions in Vives (1999)

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory

I have trouble in understanding why a sufficient condition that a best reply function is a contraction. The following is a screenshot of Xavier Vives's *Oligopoly Pricing: Old Ideas and New Tools* from googlebooks (see [here](https://books.google.de/books?redir_esc=y&id=le-OE5HMLY8C&q=47#v=snippet&q=47&f=false)):

[image]

We have to find a constant $c \in [0,1)$ such that for all $x, y \in A$,
$$d(r(x),r(y)) \leq c d(x,y)$$

But it seems to me we don't have any parameter in this setting to calculate $c$.

Comment: Check out [this document](http://opim.wharton.upenn.edu/~cachon/pdf/cachon_netessine_gt.pdf), section 2.4.2 on p.17.